# DB Connection on Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, database-connection

I have a chat on my website, and it runs on AJAX calls.  Knowing that the PHP script is being ran 2-3 times per second, is it a bad idea to connect to a database and pull / insert data?  I am wondering if it will slow down my PHP significantly, or not change it much at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment yet, so i don't know if that's your answer..

So basically of course this will cause all lot of traffic on your database. Depending on Webserver this might not be that big of a deal. But if a Clients physic computer is just from 2000, his side will just lag out the tab because his browser is sending all the time requests to your database and is trying to get the answer.

But i think this is the easiest method to get live data, which you need for your chat. But in my opinion I would suggest you to run the AJAX-Request like every 2 Seconds. I don't know what's exactly your purpose. But for a normal chat (not real time data exchange) this will last.

By the way: I am also not sure how you are initializing your AJAX-Request. But i would suggest doing this with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    call_php_ajax()
});

function call_php_ajax(){
    $("#div_toinsert").load("ajax.php");
    setTimeout(call_php_ajax, 3000)  // 3 Seconds
```

And in your MySQL-Query-File (ajax.php) you perform your queries